# How to Check if an Argument Was Called Without an Action?

Tags: python

I want to be able to see if an argument was called without using the store action. Instead of my code looking like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-a', '--argument',
action="store", dest="some_arg",
    help='Help data..', default="none")

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.some_arg == "user input":
    print "Argument was called."
```

I want the user not have to enter in "user input" to get the same result as `print "Argument was called"`. In other words if the user wanted to reference this argument he would just have type:

```
script.py --argument
```

Instead of:

```
script.py --argument user input
```

Comment: This question is basically incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `store_true` action. This will set the value to `True` if the argument was specified, or `False` otherwise:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.foo:
    print('--foo was specified')
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad someone understands.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work the way we both thought. It's actually running whatever is in the if statement weather it was specified or not.

Comment: @NoahR It's working for me, it only prints that line if `--foo` was specified. Maybe you have a bug somewhere in your code.